# C# - Get a list of representative points

Tags: c#, graph-algorithm, graphing

I have a method that returns thousands of points to be displayed in a dygraph section in frontend, it is feed with a list like this:

```
  List<int> pointsResult = GetMyPoints();
```

This graph is a very small graph where I think only the representative points could be displayed.

What could be the best approach to just get for example 100 values instead of thousands?

This int values can be very regular and only the representative points will need to be displayed.

The graph looks like:

[image]

Comment: the "Ramer–Douglas–Peucker" algorithm might help.

Comment: Looks like a good choice. There are [other algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm#Other_line_simplification_algorithms), though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this C# implementation

> [A C# Implementation of Douglas-Peucker Line Approximation
>   Algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18936/A-Csharp-Implementation-of-Douglas-Peucker-Line-Ap)

```
public static List<Point> DouglasPeuckerReduction
    (List<Point> Points, Double Tolerance)
{
    if (Points == null || Points.Count < 3)
    return Points;

    Int32 firstPoint = 0;
    Int32 lastPoint = Points.Count - 1;
    List<Int32> pointIndexsToKeep = new List<Int32>();

    //Add the first and last index to the keepers
    pointIndexsToKeep.Add(firstPoint);
    pointIndexsToKeep.Add(lastPoint);

    //The first and the last point cannot be the same
    while (Points[firstPoint].Equals(Points[lastPoint]))
    {
        lastPoint--;
    }

    DouglasPeuckerReduction(Points, firstPoint, lastPoint, 
    Tolerance, ref pointIndexsToKeep);

    List<Point> returnPoints = new List<Point>();
    pointIndexsToKeep.Sort();
    foreach (Int32 index in pointIndexsToKeep)
    {
        returnPoints.Add(Points[index]);
    }

    return returnPoints;
}
```